# Aggregation functions in the scala library

Tags: scala, collections

Consider

```
   val myseq = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
   val mysum = myseq.foldLeft(0){_ + _}
```

Is there not a defined aggregator for sum(), count(), etc? Along the lines of:

```
   import math.SomeLibraryClass._

   val myseq = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
   val mysum = myseq.foldLeft(0.0)(sum)
```

Or for the case of groups of (row-based) sums:

```
   val rowSums = rows.map {sum}
```

(where by default the initial value is 0)

**Update**

So from the comments it appears there is no *static* (scala object-based) method for this and the correct syntax is:

```
   val rowSums = rows.map {_.sum}
```

Here it is:

```
scala> val arr = Array(Array(1,2,3), Array(4,5,6))
arr: Array[Array[Int]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 3), Array(4, 5, 6))

scala> arr.map(_.sum)
res23: Array[Int] = Array(6, 15)
```

Comment: Like `Array(1,2,3,4,5).sum`

Comment: @m-z yes, that .. I am looking now to see where that "lives" in the library.  OK in TraversableOnce - which is where we would expect .. so must be my usage is not optimal.

Comment: @javadba http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@sum:A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, there's already a `sum` method defined on collections, though it requires an implicit `Numeric[A]` for some `M[A]`.

Perhaps you may be interested in the methods contained in the `Numeric` trait. For example, `sum` is defined in `TraversableOnce` like this:

```
def sum[B >: A](implicit num: Numeric[B]): B = foldLeft(num.zero)(num.plus)
```

So in a sense, Scala *does* have some static references to methods like `sum`. There are quite a few instances of `Numeric` in the standard library, for each numeric type. ([seen here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Numeric))

For instance, there is `IntIsIntegral`, which a `Numeric[Int]`. You *could* use it explicitly like this:

```
Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5).fold(Numeric.IntIsIntegral.zero)(Numeric.IntIsIntegral.plus)
```

But why would you want to? The thing is, this will only work for `Int`, when requiring an implicit `Numeric[A]` will work for any numeric type that has such an implicit defined.

This breaks, since the types are different:

```
scala> Array(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0).fold(Numeric.IntIsIntegral.zero)(Numeric.IntIsIntegral.plus)
<console>:8: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int) => Int
 required: (AnyVal, AnyVal) => AnyVal
              Array(1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0).fold(Numeric.IntIsIntegral.zero)(Numeric.IntIsIntegral.plus)
```

So, technically yes, functions like that exist. But using `Numeric` in this case is better.

Comment: After reading your answer, it still seems that the correct usage is as shown in my update: i.e. an instance-based _.sum as opposed to object based sum. If I have interpreted your answer incorrectly pls elaborate ;) Anyways am upvoting.

Comment: @javadba I'm not saying that using the static objects is correct--I'm just stating that such things do exist. Using `Array(..).sum` and `matrix.map(_.sum)` is certainly better. i.e. taking advantage of things that are in the standard collections library. However, if you need to implement some custom generic numeric aggregation, then the `Numeric` trait is definitely something to check out.